# Make calculation from two subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to know what is the correct syntax to make something similar to this:

```
SELECT calculation1, calculation2 FROM
    (SELECT name, x/y as calculation1 FROM data) X
    (SELECT name, a/b as calculation2 FROM data) Y
WHERE calculation1 > 10;
```

It works fine for one single single query, tho:

```
 SELECT calculation1 FROM
    (SELECT name, x/y as calculation1 FROM data) X
 WHERE calculation1 > 10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT calculation1, calculation2 FROM
    (SELECT name, x/y as calculation1, a/b as calculation2  FROM data) X
WHERE calculation1 > 10;
```